# If $M$ is a positive definite matrix, is $AMA^{-1}$ a positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

> If $M$ is a positive definite matrix, is $AMA^{-1}$ a positive definite matrix?

*Notes*

I am assuming that $A$ is a general matrix. If this property does not hold true for general matrices then what conditions on $A$ are needed? My intuition is that the symmetric part of $AMA^{-1}$ is positive definite as $M$ has the same eigenvalues as $AMA^{-1}$.

**Work thus far**

Let $y=A^{-1}z$ and $z$ be an appropriately sized vector 
\begin{align}
z^T AMA^{-1}z&= (yA)^TA My \\
&= y^T A^TAMy 
\end{align}
If we assume that $A$ is unitary then $A^T=A^{-1}$ and we have
\begin{align}
y^T A^TAMy &= y^T A^{-1}AMy\\
&=y^TMy 
\end{align}
$y^TMy\geq 0$ for any $y$ so this implies $z^TAMA^{-1}z\geq 0$ if $A$ is unitary.

Is there any why to show the same holds true in for any $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AMA^{-1}$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $M$, but need not be symmetric (or hermitian in the complex case).  The symmetric part need not be positive definite.  For example, consider
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 3\cr 1 & 2\cr},\ M = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr},\
A M A^{-1} = \pmatrix{4 & -3\cr 2 & -1}$$
Note that $$\pmatrix{0\cr 1}^T AMA^{-1} \pmatrix{0\cr 1} < 0$$

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the example. I can see that the symmetric part of $AMA^{-1}$ is not positive definite. If $A$ is unitary (as in my question in the work thus far section) is $AMA^{-1}$ positive definite?

Comment: This is because $AMA^{-1}$ is symmetric if $A$ is unitary, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.